# Can I Access The Moon To Do The Next Step Of The Lie?

Tags: destiny-2

I am a New Light player with no DLC.

I recently completed the shotgun telemetry quest step for 'The Lie' quest. The next step tells me to go talk to Rasputin.

Rasputin is on the Moon and when I went there it placed me in a mission.

This was my first time on the moon. Whenever I open the director it says that other activities are not available at this time.

If I complete the mission, will I get access to Rasputin or can I not progress any further in the quest since I don’t own Shadowkeep or Forsaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to play the initial story mission of Shadowkeep even without any DLC which unlocks access to the Moon as a patrol zone. Simply select the Moon from the director and hit go.